# woocommerce cart redirects to localhost

Tags: redirect, localhost, woocommerce

My online woocomerce site redirects to localhost when going to the cart. I've had similar problems with wordpress sites in general before - but now it's only the cart/checkout pages. Shop works fine.

Any database tables that need fixing?

Comment: Can you provide us a code you are working with?

Comment: Do a search on the db for local host entries. Also be careful when doing local dev as some of the wp settings use a serialised URL. This means "http://localhost" != "http://production.com" and tends to break a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Search and Replace DB](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) tool. [Here](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/move-wordpress/) are the instructions how to use it. It’s very simple, but be carefull with search and replace terms, or you might ruin the database. Make sure to backup up the database.

Answer (score 0):

I found an entry in my wordpress options table where I changed

```
http://localhost/mysite
```

to

```
http://www.mysite.url
```

Now everything is fine!